# Ansible: Set an ACL to files and directories

Tags: ansible, acl

I know how to use the acl module in ansible. It's working like a charm but not exactly like I want.

I have a log_dir variable with the exact path to log files. My goal is to set an ACL to the files and only to the parent directories up to a base directory.

For example:

**Log file**: /some/highly/fancy/secured/file

**Log path**: /some/highly/fancy/secured

Now I want an ACL up to /some but not to (for example):

/some/otherDirectory or /some/highly/fancy/A/file

Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: Sorry but, could you provide some code with the `playbook` you are currently using? I am having a hard time trying to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feels super hacky, but something like this would work. I do hope there's a more elegant solution though.

```
  vars:
    file: /some/highly/fancy/secured/file

  tasks:
    - acl:
        path: "/{{ file.split('/')[1:index+2] | join('/') }}"
        # <snip>
      loop: "{{ file.split('/')[1:] }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: index
```

Basic idea is to use the file path split into a list to figure out how many times to loop. Then inside the loop once again split the file path into a list, and slice it from the base folder up to the loop index, and join it again into a file path. We skip the first entry in the list because it is blank, so need to adjust the index value in the list slice.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the solution! Honestly, I'm not the fittest one to ansible, so I think I would have spent a lot of time on investigating...
It's exactly what I wanted!
Many thanks

Comment: How did you get to this solution? Are there any docs that I can study? Eg where do I find [1:index+2] explained?

Comment: List splitting/joining just comes from a background in Python and programming in general. It definitely doesn't hurt to understand a bit about data structures and how to manipulate them in Python